# Читаемые url на кириллице в логах logging python

Tags: python-3.x, 1с, логирование

Создаю приложение на python, которое выдергивает данные rest-запросами c web-сервера 1с.

Использую logging

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_for_logging,
                encoding='utf-8',
                level=logging.DEBUG,
                format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s: %(lineno)d - %(message)s")
```

В лог-файле получаю это:

2021-11-29 12:37:47,843 - DEBUG - *make_request: 452 - http://i5:80 "GET /service/ru_RU//odata/standard.odata/Catalog*%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0?&$filter=Code%20eq%20'123456'&$format=json;odata=nometadata HTTP/1.1" 200 17

Ну а хотелось бы по возможности так:

2021-11-29 12:37:47,843 - DEBUG - _make_request: 452 - http://i5:80 "GET /service/ru_RU//odata/standard.odata/Catalog_СерийныеНомера?&$filter=Code eq '123456'&$format=json;odata=nometadata HTTP/1.1" 200 17

Comment: А в лог то вы пишете, или оно само как-то пишет? Это стандартный `url-encode` для ссылок.

Comment: В лог-файл пишет сам модуль logging, все его настройки в коде выше